# Centralizar span dentro do circulo

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como centralizar o **+** na horizontal e vertical de forma que fique fixo em qualquer tamanho?

Estou fazendo aqui, mas o posicionamento do **+**, está ficando diferente, no meu computador fica centralizado, agora abrindo no notebook que tem monitor menor o **+** fica mais para cima.

Outro pronto, é como posicionar a circulo na direita.

Obrigado.

```css
.icoAdd {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #3880ff;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.icoAdd span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 29%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="icoAdd">
  <span>+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é usar `display: flex` no parent em vez de `position: absolute` na span.

Como tem .icoAdd com `position: absolute` `right: 0` fica à direita.

```css
.icoAdd {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #3880ff;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icoAdd span {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white; 
}
```

```html
<div class="icoAdd">
    <span>+</span>
</div>
```